# TemplateDoesNotExist at /student/login/ , although the template with proper name exits

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am a beginner in Django and I'm trying to learn. I can't figure out the cause of the error, the template name is defined as per the documentation students/student_detail.html. My intuition is that the detail view is not able to find Student Model. or there's not a proper implementation of the DetailView

Error

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /student/login/
/student/5/detail/
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/student/login/
Django Version: 3.0.2
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
/student/5/detail/
Exception Location: C:\Users\Madhu\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in get_template, line 19
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Madhu\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.1
Python Path:    
['D:\\python\\DJANGO_COURSE_2.xx\\Practice1\\Library',
 'C:\\Users\\Madhu\\Anaconda3\\envs\\MyDjangoEnv\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Madhu\\Anaconda3\\envs\\MyDjangoEnv\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Madhu\\Anaconda3\\envs\\MyDjangoEnv\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Madhu\\Anaconda3\\envs\\MyDjangoEnv',
 'C:\\Users\\Madhu\\Anaconda3\\envs\\MyDjangoEnv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 30 Apr 2020 06:12:11 +0000
Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

This engine did not provide a list of tried templates.
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
#Url patterns
app_name = 'students'

urlpatterns=[
    path('signup/',views.studentsignup, name='signup'),
    path('<int:pk>/detail/',views.StudentDetailView.as_view(),name='detail'),
    path('login/',views.loginPage, name='login'),
]
```

views.py

```
def loginPage(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        #if request method is post
        form = Login(request.POST)
        print('method is post')
        if form.is_valid():
            # if form is valid then
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = User.objects.get(email=email)
            print('user is authenticated',user)

            if user is not None:
                # if user exists then
                login(request,user)
                print('student login done')
                return render(request,reverse('students:detail',args=[user.student.id]))
            else:
                # if user has entered invalid Credentials or not present
                print('invalid Credentials')
                message = 'Invalid Credentials or SignUp'
                form = Login()
                return render(request,'students/login.html',context={'message':message,'form':form})
        else:
            print('invalid form')
            message = 'Invalid form'
            return render(request,'students/login.html',context={'message':message,'form':form})
    else:
        #if request method is get
        form = Login()
        return render(request, 'students/login.html',{'form':form})


class StudentDetailView(generic.DetailView,mixins.LoginRequiredMixin):
    model = Student
    template_name = 'students/students_detail.html'
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.TextField(max_length=256)
    roll_no = models.IntegerField()
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    sem = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('students:detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

Settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
[enter image description here][1]

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'y$y!x0%h9v+1crht_qmp_x2)1hy9r&m-m05f6hz#3@x4)ap-8h'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'books.apps.BooksConfig',
    'students.apps.StudentsConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'library.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'library.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to show project stucture and settings.py

Did your template in app folder?

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder named templates in the directory where the app(where there is admin.py located) is located and transfer all your templates in that folder , make sure u have these settings in ur manage.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

And in the installed app list add your app name . Make sure to direct only file name in urls.py instead of the path.